# javascript code to make sure if an iframe has loaded completely

Tags: iframe

I want to retrieve content of a web page loaded in iframe- I understood (from other Q&As on Stack Overflow) that this can be done using the following code :

```
document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

Please clarify the following for me :

> It should be ensured that the iframe has completely loaded, before
>   running the above command.

How do I ensure this? (In javascript or java/jsp)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery("div#iframe_holder > iframe").load(function() {
  // do something when iframe is done loading 
});
```